# django date filter gte and lte

Tags: django, django-views, django-filters

I need to find data within a certain set of parameters
I am building a small booking system, that lets user see what vehicles are available for booking for their little safari trip.

The system has bookings that have been entered previously or made previously by a client.

If a booking's `pickup_date = 2011-03-01` and `dropoff_date = 2011-03-15` and I run a query with `pickup=2011-03-09` and `dropoff=2011-03-14` in my views as below, it doesn't return any results to see if a booking within that timeframe has been made.

**views.py**

```
def dates(request, template_name='groups/_dates.html'):
    pickup=request.GET.get('pickup','None');
    dropoff=request.GET.get('dropoff','None');
    order = Order.objects.filter(pick_up__lte=pickup).filter(drop_off__gte=dropoff)

    context = {'order':order,}

    return render_to_response(template_name,context,
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Any suggestions on how to do this?
Or should I be looking at an alternate way of running this query?

Comment: are you wanting to return bookings between pickup and drop off? if so should it not be Order.objects.filter(pick_up__gte=pickup, drop_off__lte=dropoff) e.g any orders between or equal to 2011-03-09 and 2011-03-14? Or have i misunderstood the requirement?

Comment: Well If I, the customer, am looking to book a vehicle and my dates are 2011-03-09, as pickup, and 2011-03-14, as dropoff, and another booking is already on the system that has a date of 2011-03-01, as pickup, and 2011-03-15, as dropoff, I want the system to tell me that this time slot is taken. Makes more sense now?

Comment: I would always recommend using a form to sanitize input.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Could it be posible that as your passing the raw string to the queryset is not on the correct format, try converting the strings to datetime objects.

Later you can try using the range lookup is more efficient on some DB engines and more simple to read and code.

```
from django.db.models import Q

start_date = datetime.date(2005, 1, 1)
end_date = datetime.date(2005, 3, 31)
orders = Order.objects.filter(drop_off__gte=start_date, pick_up__lte=end_date)
# Or maybe better
orders = Order.objects.filter(Q(drop_off__gte=start_date), Q(pick_up__lte=end_date))
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this :

```
order = Order.objects.filter(pick_up**__date__**lte=pickup).filter(drop_off**__date__**gte=dropoff)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#date

Comment: It's better to include information directly in the answer as well as the link so that the answer is still useful if the link goes away.

Comment: @Nick if the link goes away, it's probably because it's not supported anymore. I don't think this is an issue in this case.