# Django filter on date difference between columns

Tags: python, django

As a Django beginner I struggle with a very basic problem: Filter a table based on the date difference of two columns. I could solve this in raw SQL, but I would really want to use basic Django functions.

I have the following model:

```
  from django.db import models
  import datetime

  class Race(models.Model):
      __tablename__ = 'race'
      name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
      country = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
      start = models.DateField()
      end = models.DateField()
```

and I want to extract races that last e.g. more than 5 days. I can somehow get a timediff column:

```
Race.objects.annotate(tdiff=F('end')-F('start')).first()
set1 = Race.objects.annotate(tdiff=F('end')-F('start')).all()
set1.first().tdiff
```

Now, how do I filter on this column, what I tried is:

```
min_diff = datetime.timedelta(5)
set1.filter(tdiff__gte=5).first()
set1.all().filter(tdiff__gte=min_diff)
set1.filter(tdiff__gte=min_diff).first()
```

but this all gives:

> TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Then I considered using extra to get a where clause:

```
set2 = Race.objects.annotate(tdiff=F('end')-F('start'))
set2.first().tdiff
set2.all().extra(where=['tdiff>=5'])
```

resulting in:

> ProgrammingError: column "tdiff" does not exist

Questions in the same direction include [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245307/django-date-filter-gte-and-lte) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12380448/how-to-create-a-django-queryset-filter-comparing-two-date-fields-in-the-same-mod?rq=1) but none really give a solution where you filter on a new column (here tdiff).

---

When finalizing this question I in the end did get the result that I wanted by:

```
Race.objects.filter(end__gte=F("start")+5)
print(Race.objects.filter(end__gte=F("start")+5).query)
```

but I still very much would like to know how to utilize this temporary column tdiff.

Thanks!

---

### Update after answer

The accepted answer gives exactly what I wanted:

```
from django.db.models import DurationField, F, ExpressionWrapper
import datetime

set4 = Race.objects.annotate(    
    diff=ExpressionWrapper(F('end') - F('start'), output_field=DurationField())).filter(
    diff__gte=datetime.timedelta(5))
len(set4)
# 364
len(Race.objects.filter(end__gte=F("start")+5))
# 364
```

Comment: What is the `output_field` type of `tdiff` after applying your `F()` functions? My guess is that since your `start` and `end` fields are DateTime, you have to specify the `output_field` of `tdiff` as [`DurationField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#durationfield) using [`ExpressionWrapper`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/expressions/#expressionwrapper-expressions). Then you should be able to run a filter on the field against python's `timedelta` type. `Race.objects.annotate(tdiff=ExpressionWrapper(F('end')-F('start'), output_field=DurationField()))`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This would do the magic:

```
from django.db.models import DurationField, F, ExpressionWrapper
import datetime

Race.objects.annotate(
    diff=ExpressionWrapper(F('end') - F('start'), output_field=DurationField())
).filter(diff__gte=datetime.timedelta(5))
```

This will return all `Race` instances whose duration is greater than or equal to `5`

References:

- [`ExpressionWrapper`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/expressions/#expressionwrapper-expressions)
- SO Post - [How should I use DurationField in my model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30222660/how-should-i-use-durationfield-in-my-model)-

Comment: Thanks; this works! I will update the question with the results and show that it gives the same result as the basic solution I had.