# Django filter by date range and if no records in a date, return dummy records in that without being dead in loop

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I have a very unique requirement and I have not noticed such a solution on Django documentation.

Also, I don't want to use any `loop` after the database query even though I can achieve such a solution with `loop` over all the records.

```
class Example(models.Model):
    date = DateField
    name = CharField
```

and Let's say i have following records in the table

```
[
 {date: "2018-01-05", name="jhon doe"},
 {date: "2018-01-11", name="jonathan someone"},
 {date: "2018-01-21", name="someone developer"},
]
```

and my query:

```
Example.objects.filter(date_range=["2018-01-01", "2018-01-31"])
```

As normal when we query with a date range, it returns all the records within that range. it's expected and normal.

But I want it should come with a blank record when there are no records on a certain date range.

As we notice I have only 3 records in that range, so I am expecting a result like this

```
[
 {date: "2018-01-01", name="Not Found"},
 {date: "2018-01-02", name="Not Found"},
 {date: "2018-01-03", name="Not Found"},
 {date: "2018-01-04", name="Not Found"},
 {date: "2018-01-05", name="jhon doe"},
 {date: "2018-01-06", name="Not found"},
 '''''to be continued in a range''''
]
```

Is there anyone who knows to prepare queryset like above this during filter? I need it like this coz, i am using a javascript tool in the frontend, it expects data like this.

Even though i can achieve this with frontend writing a utility function in frontend or looping over all the queryset and prepare the date above way.

Does anyone have a solution except being sunk in the loop?

I appreciate your constructive answer

Comment: I don't understand that is that possible at all? Because other records that does not in that date range does not exists in your database. So you have to create new records but not to save them in your database. Then you should write your queries to get the values in desired format.

Comment: [Try this method of lte and gte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245307/django-date-filter-gte-and-lte) and check for `QS.count()` method if it is zero return the output using plain python query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have already made a comment says that it is not possible, of course depending on my knowledge but I want to explain why and how can this be solved.

Lets say you have your `Example` model class with those 3 records. When you make this query; `Example.objects.filter(date_range=["2018-01-01", "2018-01-31"])` it will bring those records in that range like you said but there is no  way that it fetches a records like

```py
{date: "2018-01-01", name="Not Found"},
{date: "2018-01-02", name="Not Found"}...
```

because those objects does not exists in your database actually. I think you have to use a loop to create those records that does not in the db. It can be done as:

```py
# Initialize your start and end date
date_start = datetime.date(2018, 1, 1)
date_end = datetime.date(2018, 1, 31)

# Get only the dates so that we can find what is not in that range
example_dates = Example.objects.values_list('date', flat=True) 

# Initialize new list that will include records does not exists
not_found_dates = []

# Loop through in date range and if date does not exists 
# Create a dict and add it to your list
for i in range(1, (date_start - date_end).days + 1):
    new_date = date_start + datetime.timedelta(days=i)
    if new_date not in dates:
        not_found_dates.append({'date': new_date, 'name': 'Not Found'}) 

# Get your original queryset
examples = Example.objects.filter(date__range=(date_start, date_end)).values('date', 'name')
# Convert it to a list
examples = list(examples)
# Than extends examples with other list
examples.extend(example_dates)
```

If you want to use your serializer to convert your queryset, instead of creating dictionaries as records you should create objects like `example=Example.objects.create(**kwargs)` and merge 2 queryset so that your serializer can manipulate it. But this will create new records in your database so it is may not be a good approach also.

Comment: Yes, Creating new records is bad approch. so i think i have to use for loop at any means

Comment: It seems like it. Hope this helps/solves your problem.

Comment: I am actually worried about performance as there are lots of data in db. Yet i thought same way before i post it. so i had to accept your answer.

I appreciate you for your response

Comment: Yes, this is an O(nk) operation but I could not find a better solution for this. Only thing I can think of is that if your date is uniqe instead of converting in to a list you can convert it to a dictionary which has a O(1)  time complexity of membership operations so this code will be executed in O(n) which is not so bad. Other than that maybe you can try to fetch queryset with raw sql. I think it can improve the execution time slightly.